# Automatically wrap acronyms or words in caps with <span>

Tags: replace

I’d like to format all acronyms and words in caps automatically with a `<span>` tag to format them via CSS.

Examples:

```
I live in the <span class="smcp">USA</span>.
My <span class="smcp">IP</span>-address is 0.0.0.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a Regex replace:
`([A-Z][A-Z]+)`
to
`<span class="smcp">\1</span>`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am really new to PHP so I would be totally happy if you could post the whole regex.

Comment: This is whole regex. And if you want to convert it to PHP, do it yourself. I don't know if there are any differences. Also, if your question is specific to PHP, why didn't you add a tag?